# AppEngine - while Google is spinning new instances, serve 'We're sorry' notification

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

Sometimes when starting up a new instance on AppEngine the process may take some time. It obviously depends on your choice of libraries etc. My question is, is it possible to serve some other page while users are waiting? [Reddit does a nice job of this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp29ascsimax7e0/Reddit.png). Other sites like Twitter provide a similar notice to users when the load is too much (they probably also starting more instances in the bg).

Does anybody have any experience in doing this on GAE?

Comment: There is no real means to do what you want unless you initial page load is from a static resource and you then use ajax calls to load the content.  Are you using warmup requests ? that can make a big difference.  Also if you primary page is heavily cacheable and you can serve the cache data from memcache without loading 3rd party libs you can get fast instance startup times - at least you can with python.

Answer (score -1):

Another twisted way that is very simple to implement without code changes: use another appengine that statically serves a tiny html of just an iframe to your real appengine.
This might break TOS so check that before doing it. It sill cost you more too.
That wrapper appengine can serve js that does the "loading" page , inserts the iframe and lster removes its content when hidden iframe  finishes loading, then shows the iframe

Comment: Why would you use a seperate appengine instance to server static html?  serving static content does not rely on a running instance. Its served from different infrastructure

Comment: My answer still applies though. Have that static page be part of the same appengine.

Comment: @ZigMandel Tim already suggested loading a static resource; I read your answer as primarily suggesting the use of a second App Engine application in order to do so.  I consider that bad advice for multiple reasons, including the fact that it doesn't gain you anything.